# Is it worth writing a SPA if I have to make 2 API requests instead of 1 each time?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, rest, http-post, single-page-application

I want to build a SPA but, for security reasons, I can't make the REST API calls directly from the browser. Instead, I have to make an ajax call to the server and then, have it make the REST request. If I was not doing a SPA, I could just have the one request on the server-side. And each of my pages ends with a POST request so I have to do this every time I switch routes. Do I still get the benefits that come from a SPA if it doubles my requests?

Comment: If you can't use your current REST API, why don't you just setup a public REST API (with necessary security precautions) that simply forwards the calls to your private API?

Comment: Is that a better option than sending it to the server and having it forward to the private API? I didn't write the API and I'm not sure how I'd go about changing it to make it secure if I still need to use the browser to send all the information it needs to make the secure call.

Comment: Even if you were doing everything server-side, your users browsers are still making a GET request to your sever when they visit a URL on your domain. I don't exactly understand why there is a security issue if this REST API was previously acceptable.

Comment: Also, about your actual question, 2 API requests shouldn't be a big deal. Even if you did it server-side, there would still be 2 requests. One for originally requesting the page, and another for your POST request.